# Import files to excel workbook, then process the files and copy into another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to create a sub that will let a user select a directory, search the directory for a given file type, import data of a given type to a spreadsheet for data processing, and then take the processed data and write it to a data log spreadsheet for simple analysis.

Additional things that I'm going to try and implement are using the `FileSystemObject` instead of `Application.FileDialog` to identify a directory to loop through.

```
Option Explicit    
Sub reflectivity()

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.EnableEvents = False
'This code prompts a user for a directory that contains files of type extType,
'then extracts average values that are defined by r1,r2,r3 and writes them,
'along with the file name to the next open cell in the workbook aBook including
'a blank line after each directory worth of files
'then it closes the books and saves the changes

        Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
        Dim Tr1 As Range, Tr2 As Range, Tr3 As Range, Tr4 As Range
        Dim strTr1 As String, strTr2 As String, strTr3 As String
        Dim meas1 As Double, meas2 As Double, meas3 As Double
        Dim fDialog As FileDialog
        Dim pathName As String, extType As String, operFile As String, targetPath As String, targetpath2 As String, fileType As String
        Dim prefix As String, file As String
        Dim count As Integer, nextEntry As Integer
        Dim aBook As Workbook, bBook As Workbook
        Dim aSheet As Worksheet, bSheet As Worksheet

'you can change targetPath to a workbook that you want to use as an intermediate for the calculation
        targetPath = "C:\Users\SOME_USER\Desktop\Test1\test1.xlsx"
        Set aBook = Workbooks.Open(targetPath)
        Set aSheet = aBook.Worksheets(1)
'       Set aBook = ThisWorkbook
'       If aBook.Worksheets("Calc") <> 0 Then
'            aSheet = aBook.Worksheets("Calc")
'            Else: aSheet = aBook.Worksheets("Calc").Add
'       End If

'set bSheet to the workbook where you want to add the summarized data
        targetpath2 = "C:\users\SOME_USER\desktop\TEMP\test book-2.xlsm"
        Set bBook = ThisWorkbook
        Set bSheet = bBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'choose which type of file has your data to extract
        fileType = "*.csv"

'get path for files to be processed from user
        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            With fDialog
                .Title = "Select Directory"
                .ButtonName = "Select"
                .AllowMultiSelect = False
                If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
                pathName = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            End With

            extType = fileType
            operFile = Dir(pathName & extType)
            prefix = "TEXT;"

'open csv into sheet(1) and csv_get it

            Set r1 = Range("B43:B89")
            'Set r1 = [average(Result!B43:B89)]
            Set r2 = Range("B152:B199")
            Set r3 = Range("B311:B352")

            Do While operFile <> ""
                file = prefix & pathName & operFile
                With aSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=file, Destination:=aSheet.Range("A1"))
                    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                    .Refresh
                End With

                'first cell gets written
                meas1 = csv_get(r1, aBook, aSheet)

                'second cell gets written
                meas2 = csv_get(r2, aBook, aSheet)

                'third cell gets written
                meas3 = csv_get(r3, aBook, aSheet)

                Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents

                'this part finds the next line in the bSheet and writes the measurements to the new line

                nextEntry = nextLine(bBook, bSheet)
                        strTr1 = "C" & nextEntry
                        strTr2 = "D" & nextEntry
                        strTr3 = "E" & nextEntry
                        strtitle = "A" & nextEntry

                        Set Tr1 = Range(strTr1)
                        Set Tr2 = Range(strTr2)
                        Set Tr3 = Range(strTr3)
                        Set Tr4 = Range(strtitle)

                    With bSheet
                        Tr1.Value = meas1
                        Tr2.Value = meas2
                        Tr3.Value = meas3
                        Tr4.Value = operFile

                    End With

            operFile = Dir()

            Loop

NextCode:
'in case of cancel
            pathName = pathName
            If pathName = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error GoTo nothingtodelete
            aSheet.QueryTables(1).SaveData = False
            aSheet.QueryTables.Item(1).Delete
nothingtodelete:
aBook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub

Public Function csv_get(locString As Range, wBook As Workbook, wSheet As Worksheet) As Variant

Dim pathName As String

    wBook.Activate
    wSheet.Activate

        csv_get = wSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(locString)
End Function
Public Function nextLine(wBook As Workbook, wSheet As Worksheet) As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer

    wBook.Activate
    With wSheet

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wSheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
            nextLine = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
        Else
            nextLine = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Disheartening downvotes.. anyone care to comment?

Answer (score 0):

It took me longer than expected to write this code, but I wanted to post it since I had trouble finding the tools that I needed to make this code work. Cheers and thanks for any feedback!

In order to use an FSO, I replaced the `FileDialog` method with this code:

`Dim objFSO as new FileSystemObject
    Dim objStartFolder as Folder
    Dim objFolder as Folder
    Dim colFiles as Collection
        set objFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        objStartFolder = "\\folder"
        set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
            For i=1 to colFiles.count
                run csv_get and nextline
            next i
        Subfolder_Search objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
        function Subfolder_Search(folder)
            For i=1 to Folder.SubFolders.count
               Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
                Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
                    For i=1 to colFiles.count
                        run csv_get and nextLine
                    Next i
                Subfolder_Search Subfolder
            Next i
        end function`